Spring: Passing information down to child methods
Here's the problem I'm trying to solve:
I've got a number of entry points into my system. e.g REST endpoints, Queue listeners, and let's suppose more in the future. I'd like to set some contextual information to make available to all service methods (these can call other service methods in turn, creating a DAG of calls).
One way to think about this would be for all my service methods to take an extra context parameter, which they then pass down.
Another (less powerful) way to think about this would be to save this information on a bean under WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST. As I understand them, these won't maintain the bean for asynchronously running CompletableFutures. These also won't work for non-http requests (e.g the queue).
It looks like my options are:

Refactor all my methods to take in a new context param. Downside is that this is a massive refactor where most methods will take in a param and do nothing more than pass it down.
Implement a new spring scope (like WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST). I'd like to refrain from adding this sort of complexity unless actually needed.

Are there other cleaner options I'm just not seeing? I can't help but feel this should be a common problem with solution patterns.

ThreadLocal variables are a current option. In the (near) future, Scoped Values will be a better option.
